# Sort duplicate values column A from csv file

Tags: python

I am trying to sort duplicate values column A from csv file but not getting expected result in python.

Input File: (.csv)

Column names:

```
Uniprot Acc, PDB ID, Ligand ID, Structure Title, Uniprot Recommended Name, Gene Name, Macromolecular Name
```

I want to sort duplicates values and single of Uniport Acc column along with pdb id and ligand id.

```
 Input file:
 Uni port Acc  PDB ID  Ligand ID
 * P0AET8   1AHI    NAI
 * P04036   1ARZ    NAI
 * Q59771   1C1D    NAI
 * P0C0F4   1DLJ    NAI
 * Q9QYY9   1E3E    NAI
 * Q9QYY9   1E3I    NAI
 * Q14376   1EK6    NAI
 * Q16836   1F17    NAI
 * P0AET8   1FMC    NAI
 * Q46220   1GIQ    NAI
 * P97852   1GZ6    NAI
 * P07195   1I0Z    NAI
 * P00338   1I10    NAI
 * P11986   1JKI    NAI
 * P10760   1KY5    NAI
 * Q2RSB2   1L7E    NAI
 * Q27743   1LDG    NAI
 * O32080   1LSU    NAI
 * P00334   1MG5    NAI
 * P26392   1N2S    NAI
 * P9WGT1   1NFQ    NAI
 * P0ABH7   1NXG    NAI
 * P05091   1NZW    NAI
 * P05091   1NZZ    NAI
 * P27443   1O0S    NAI
 * P0A6D5   1O9B    NAI
 * P20974   1OG4    NAI
 * P11986   1P1J    NAI

 Expected Result:
 Uni port Acc  PDB ID  Ligand ID
 * P0AET8   1AHI    NAI
 * P0AET8   1FMC    NAI
 * P04036   1ARZ    NAI
 * Q59771   1C1D    NAI
 * P0C0F4   1DLJ    NAI
 * Q9QYY9   1E3E    NAI
 * Q9QYY9   1E3I    NAI
   .
   .
   .





 I want to sort how many uniport acc id same with pdb id along with single id, No need to remove any id.
```

Code:

```
import csv
import re
import sys
import os

f1 = csv.reader(open('one.csv', 'rb'))

writer = csv.writer(open("Output_file_1.csv", "wb"))
def has_duplicates(f1):    
    for i in range(0, len(f1)):
        for x in range(i + 1, len(f1)):
            if f1[i] == f1[x]:
                var = f1[i]                    
                writer.writerow(var)
```

Comment: Where exactly are you sorting/trying to sort anything?! As far as I can see, you only write the rows that have duplicates in the output file. However, if a row is repeated `k` times, you will find it `k * (k - 1) / 2` times in your output file. Is this on purpose?

Comment: do you mean you are trying to **separate** the duplicate rows into a different file?

Comment: I am trying to sort duplicate value in column A along with other details is in row

Answer (score 1):

You can first store all the values in a list then you can easily find the duplicate values in a sorted order. see my below code.

```
  import csv
  import re
  import sys
  import os

  f1 = csv.reader(open('one.csv', 'rb'))

  writer = csv.writer(open("Output_file_1.csv", "wb"))

  def has_duplicates(f1):
      list = []
      for i in range(0, len(f1)):
          list.append(f1[i])
      for var in set([x for x in list if list.count(x) > 1]):
          writer.writerow(var)  # print only duplicate values in a sorted list
```

## new edits as pr your expected result

if can use `sorted` for this but this will give your expected result but little bit difference are there. You can use the following code to get the expected result.

```
def sort_duplicates(f1):
      for i in range(0, len(f1)):
          f1.insert(f1.index(f1[i])+1, f1[i])
          f1.pop(i+1)
for var in f1:
     writer.writerow(var)
```

I have tested with a list. This is result screen shot..

```
>>> a=['P0AET8', 'Q59771', 'P0C0F4','DFC4H', 'P0AET8','Q59771','ACG5D']
>>> print sorted(a)
['ACG5D', 'DFC4H', 'P0AET8', 'P0AET8', 'P0C0F4', 'Q59771', 'Q59771']
```

And if you use the above code then this is result.

```
>>> a=['P0AET8', 'Q59771', 'P0C0F4','DFC4H', 'P0AET8','Q59771','ACG5D']
>>> for i in range(0,len(a)):
...             a.insert(a.index(a[i])+1, a[i])
...             a.pop(i+1)

>>> print a
['P0AET8', 'P0AET8', 'Q59771', 'Q59771', 'P0C0F4', 'DFC4H', 'ACG5D']
```

Comment: It would be nice to add some description to your solution.

Comment: Note that this still has quadratic complexity, and the lines might end up in any order in the output file. Better add the lines to a set, and when a line is already in the set, write it to the output file.

Comment: Hi @SumanKalyan, I tried above code but I am getting output. Output file is blank...

Comment: Make sure you have some duplicate values.. if there are no duplicate values then the output will be blank..@krish

Comment: @SumanKalyan .. I have edited above along with input file and expected result. pl help

Comment: check my edited answer as per your expected result@krish

Comment: Hi@SumanKalyan I am getting null output in output file is blank .... no output.. pl help dear

Comment: So this is your CSV read and write problem..debug your code and check data is coming or not after reading..

Comment: Hi@SumanKalyan Thanks for your help, Now I am getting expected result but when i am writing output file, I am getting result each letter in separate column in csv format.

Comment: you can use a dictionary...follow this link, how to write to a csv file..https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html    and use same dictionary key in for loop during writing

Comment: I am write this code but not working : with open('output_file_2.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
 w = csv.writer(outfile)

Comment: error is: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: @SumanKalyan Please check code: writer = csv.writer(open("Output_file_3.csv", "wb")), while using this getting result in 
each letter in separate column in csv format.